# Comparación y reescritura selectiva de un archivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un csv_1 que, simplificado, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
A,B,C
1,34,55
2,45,54
3,77,90
4,89,98
```

Un segundo csv_2 que simplificado, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
a,b
1,Y
4,Y
```

Estoy intentando escribir un tercer archivo csv_3 en el que se escriban todas las filas de datos de csv_1 menos aquellas que aparecen en csv_2. Es decir, csv_3 en este caso sería así:

```
A,B,C
2,45,54
3,77,90
```

Estoy intentando esto:

```
import csv
with open("csv_1.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as f1,\
        open("csv_2.csv", "r", encoding = 'utf8') as f2,\
            open("csv_3.csv", "w", encoding = 'utf8') as f3:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(f1, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(f2, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f3, dialect='unix', delimiter=",", quotechar='"',
                            fieldnames=("A","B","C"),
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow()
    for row1 in reader1:
        if row1["A"] not in reader2:
            writer.writerow(row1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` retorna un iterador, por lo que no puedes hacer una búsqueda sobre él con `in` de forma directa, debes obtener la columna del segundo archivo y almacenarla en alguna estructura de datos, preferiblemente en un conjunto, para poder realizar la búsqueda.

Para escribir la cabecera si usas `csv.DictWriter` debes usar el método `writeheader`.

El código debería ser algo así:

```
import csv


with open("csv_1.csv", 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as f1,\
        open("csv_2.csv", "r", encoding = 'utf8') as f2,\
            open("csv_3.csv", "w", encoding = 'utf8') as f3:

    reader1 = csv.DictReader(f1, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                             quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(f2, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                             quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f3, dialect='unix', delimiter=",", quotechar='"',
                            fieldnames=reader1.fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    csv2_A_col = {row["a"] for row in reader2}

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader1:
        if row["A"] not in csv2_A_col:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

También puedes usar `writerows` y un generador:

```
csv2_A_col = {row["a"] for row in reader2}
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(row for row in reader1 if row["A"] not in csv2_A_col)
```

---

Si se quiere escribir en el fichero de salida solo algunas columnas del fichero de entrada podemos usar el argumento `extrasaction` con el valor `'ignore'`. Por ejemplo, para el ejemplo anterior, si solo queremos obtener las columnas `A` y `C` de `csv_1` basta con hacer:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(f3, extrasaction='ignore', dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                        quotechar='"', fieldnames=("A","C"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
csv2_A_col = {row["a"] for row in reader2}
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(row for row in reader1 if row["A"] not in csv2_A_col)
```

Con lo que obtenemos:

> A,C
>   2,54
>   3,90

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla. Una duda. En csv2_A_col, siguiendo el ejemplo que puse, row debería recuperar "a" minúscula, no "A" mayúscula, ¿estoy equivocado? Por otra parte estoy obteniendo un error: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '' ¿Sabes por dónde me puedo estar equivocando?

Comment: Si para el ejemplo que pones debes recuperar "a" (`csv2_A_col = {row["a"] for row in reader2}`). En cuanto al segundo se puede deber a que el archivo `csv_1` tuyo real tiene más columnas de las que especificas en `fieldnames` de `writer` o no concuerdan los nombres. ¿Acaso solo quieres quedarte con algunas columnas de `csv_1`?

Comment: Pyring como te he comentado `fielnames` ha de recibir la cabecera de `csv_1`, con exactamente los mismos nombres y numero de columnas. He modificado la respuesta para que tome `fielnames` directamente de `csv_1`. Si quieres solo copiar en `csv_3` parte de las columnas de `csv_1` al final de la respuesta he añadido como hacerlo. Si tu problema persiste comenta o edita la pregunta dando más detalles de tu caso real y de que quieres conseguir. Un saludo.

Comment: La respuesta es muy completa y el código funciona a la perfección @JFSevilla. Muchas gracias.